# Underwater chests in video games

Tags: forces, water, moment

Many video games creators put chests with items in various places. Sometimes the chests can be found underwater. Here are two examples:

Dying Light 2

[image]

Shadow of the Tomb Raider

[image]

[image]

However, I started thinking whether it is possible to open such a chest. **Inside the chest** there is air pressure (assuming it was closed on the surface). **Outside the chest** air pressure plus huge water pressure from a two or three meter column. Pressure difference is then the hydrostatic pressure. In order to open the chest one has to supply a force $F=\Delta p\cdot A_{lid}$. In the examples above the area of the lid might be around $1m^2$. Taking the water column to be two meters, I get $F=20000N$. Nonetheless due to some lever action one might be able to reduce it by a factor of two (water pressure force applied at the center of the lid and force applied by the person is the the edge).

It might be way easier to smash the chest. Mythbusters when testing techniques for getting out of a sinking car recommended smashing the side window with a sharp object. Due to high pressure difference it was impossible to open the doors.

Is my analysis OK or maybe I am missing something important?

Comment: You're assuming the boxes are airtight. If they are not & have come to be filled with water, you should be able to open it pretty easily.

Comment: Yes, that is what I assumed. The box in the first picture looks very modern and sterile. Not sure about the second one, but bubbles emerge when you open it.

Comment: Video games don't need to follow the laws of physics. They only need to seem realistic. Emitting bubbles when opened under water might seem realistic in some game plays, and being unable to open it might be a feature of others.

Comment: If the chest is water-tight then all is explained here - [Escape trunk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_trunk).